# new Date() is not showing the correct date . Showing one day previous date

Tags: javascript, date, console

```
const date = new Date();
const [month, day, year] = [date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()];
console.log(month, day, year);
```

The console is showing one day previous date of mine. Is this the mistake of VS code ?

Comment: Please show expected result and actual result. ECMAScript months are zero indexed so if `console.log(month, day, year)` is run on 2 Apr 2022 it will return `3, 2, 2022`.

Comment: have you read the documentation of these functions/classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`day == date.getDate()`
but
`realMonth != month == date.getMonth()`
because month number is given between 0 and 11.

[mdn getMonth() return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#return_value)

Answer (score 0):

Check your system's date & time.
JavaScript picks date value from system time.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.